# What is the best way to add APM to NuxtJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

What is the right way to configure/enable an Elastic APM agent in a Nuxtjs project?

I referred [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/master/custom-stack.html#custom-stack-initialization) for a custom NodeJS app. The key takeaway was:

> It’s important that the agent is started before you require any other
> modules in your Node.js application - i.e. before http and before your
> router etc.

I added the following snippet in nuxt.config.js, but the APM agent is not started or working. I do not see any errors in the app logs.

```
var apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({
  serviceName: 'nuxt-app',
  serverUrl: 'http://ELK_APM_SERVER:8200'
})
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There's a number of different ways to run a nuxt application (static site, server rendered, dev mode, start/prod mode) -- could you update your question with information on how you're starting your nuxt application?

Comment: @AlanStorm At the time of posting the question, the project was server rendered with "nuxt start" in NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I've seen it looks like there isn't a "right" way to do this with the stock `nuxt` command line application.   The problem seems to be that while `nuxt.config.js` is the first time a user has a chance to add some javascript, that the `nuxt` command line application bootstraps the Node's HTTP frameworks before this config file is `required`.  This means the elastic agent (or any APM agent) doesn't have a chance to hook into the modules.

The [current recommendations](https://github.com/nuxt/cli/issues/4#issuecomment-752230294) from the Nuxt team appears to be

1. Invoke `nuxt` manually via `-r`

   ```
        {
          "scripts": {
            "start": "node -r elastic-apm-node node_modules/nuxt/.bin/nuxt"
          }
        }
   ```
2. Skip `nuxt` and [use NuxtJS programmatically](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/nuxt/) as a middleware in your framework of choice

   ```
        const { loadNuxt } = require('nuxt')
        const nuxtPromise = loadNuxt('start')
        app.use((req, res) => { nuxtPromise.then(nuxt => nuxt.render(req, res)) })
   ```

Comment: Thanks @AlanStorm. I used the Express server middleware to set the APM configuration.

Comment: >>node_modules/nuxt/.bin/nuxt this path does not exist in a 2022 nuxt project. What do I have to change?

Comment: @PhilippS. somehow your `npm install` is not running properly.

Answer (score 4):

We managed to get this working using a custom Nuxt module which explicitly requires the Node modules to instrument after it has initiated the APM module.

`modules/elastic-apm.js`:

```
    const apm = require('elastic-apm-node');
    const defu = require('defu');
    
    module.exports = function() {
      this.nuxt.hook('ready', async(nuxt) => {
        const runtimeConfig = defu(nuxt.options.privateRuntimeConfig, nuxt.options.publicRuntimeConfig);
        const config = (runtimeConfig.elastic && runtimeConfig.elastic.apm) || {};
    
        if (!config.serverUrl) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (!apm.isStarted())  {
          await apm.start(config);
    
          // Now explicitly require the modules we want APM to hook into, as otherwise
          // they would not be instrumented.
          //
          // Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/master/custom-stack.html
          // Modules: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-nodejs/tree/master/lib/instrumentation/modules
          require('http');
          require('http2');
          require('https');
        }
      });
    }
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```
    module.exports = {
      // Must be in modules, not buildModules
      modules: ['~/modules/elastic-apm'],
      
      publicRuntimeConfig: {
        elastic: {
          apm: {
            serverUrl: process.env.ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL,
            serviceName: 'my-nuxt-app',
            usePathAsTransactionName: true // prevent "GET unknown route" transactions
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers are outdated and from beginning incorrect (17.02.2022)

To make it work follow these steps:

1.) Create a nodeApm.js in your root dir with the following content:

```
const nodeApm = require('elastic-apm-node')

if (!nodeApm.isStarted()) { 
    nodeApm.start()
}
```

2.) Use environment variables to store your config. For example:

```
ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME=NUXT_PRODUCTION
ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN=yoursecrettokenhere
```

3.) Edit your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    // if you want apm also on dev to test, add it also here
    "dev": "node -r ./nodeApm.js node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt",
    ...
    "start": "node -r ./nodeApm.js node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt start",
...
```

! Be awere that in ~2022 the node_modules bin folder has lost the "." in the directory name

! In all othere anwsers people forget the start parameter at the end

"start": "node -r ./nodeApm.js node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt **start**",

Answer (score 1):

Based on Alan Storm answer (from Nuxt team) I made it work but with a little modification:

- I created a file named nodeApm.js where I added the following code:

  ```
  const nodeApm = require('elastic-apm-node')

  if (!nodeApm.isStarted()) { ... // configuration magic }
  ```
- In script sections I added:

  ```
  "start": "node -r ./nodeApm.js node_modules/nuxt/.bin/nuxt"
  ```

Comment: Hi, can you give us an example how to set the configuration in your example?

Comment: Sure, `if (!nodeApm.isStarted()) { nodeApm.start({serviceName: 'someName', serverUrl: 'url' ... (other config options) }) } process.nodeApm = nodeApm`.